# NYSE Ticker Changes

Tags: data, nyse

I have seen that this questions has been asked before, but I find it hard to believe that there is no existing solution, so I'm asking again: Does anyone know of a website, database (beside Eikon or Bloomberg) that offers the ticker name changes of nyse tickers?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You should visit the website [www.algoseek.com](http://www.algoseek.com).

They follow up for all ticker changes for public traded stocks for all exchanges and provide this as a separate dataset.

Also, you can check the example on their website. This dataset includes ticker changes as well as company name changes etc.

Answer (score 0):

The NYSE offers a [listing directory](https://www.nyse.com/listings_directory/stock).  I don't know how often they update it.

The Nasday provides a [Stock Symbol Change History](https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/symbol-change-history) for Naz and NYSE.

The NAsdaq provides a list of [recent and expected IPOs](https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/ipos) (as well as filings) for Naz and NYSE.